# How to manage state when user close the browser and open it immediately

Tags: asp.net

How to manage state when user close the browser and open it immediately
 like in gmail or facebook when we logged in and close the browser and and open the browser immediately it automatically logged in.

Comment: I presume you want to prevent this? I.e. when a user closes the browser and immediately reopens it, you want them to have to log in again? Don't use cookies and don't hold login data in session would be a start. In asp.net sites - the session cookie seems to stay alive when re-opening a browser and, if login details are held in session, the session carries on as if the browser had not been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data around in hidden fields or in the querystring or a combination of the two. When I do this I usually pass a UserGUID and an OrganisationGUID (or just parts of both) and another (previously randomly generated) UserID - which I encrypt. If someone tampers with the querystring or hidden field values - the chances of altering 2 GUIDS to other GUIDs that match in the database - along with the encrypted UserID - are too many trillions to one to worry about. Downside with this is a trip to the database on every page submission to validate credentials. On the other hand - it only takes a few milliseconds to do. Or you can use Session but if a user blocks all cookies the sessionstate cookies won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Same way you manage state during a browser session, you maintain a cookie containing what identifiable information you need. If the user deletes cookies when they close the browser then that's their choice, and they will know they have to re-login each time.

Comment: Is their any another way to maintain state rather than cookies?? Because sometimes user can block the cookies.